# Defining severity level, SNMPTRAP

Tags: snmp, mib, network-monitoring, snmp-trap

I want to send an SNMP trap, using snmptrap command, but I don't know how to set Severity Level.

I'm using this:

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public host "" MIB-MODULE::notificationName severity s "MINOR"
```

On the SNMPManager, the perceived severity of the trap is always "Warning"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Severity is not an attribute of an SNMP trap, in general.

Which SNMP manager are you using?

Most likely, the manager is mapping some MIB variable from the trap into the Severity field of its internal alarm format, but you're not providing that variable in your snmptrap command. You probably need to study the documentation of you SNMP manager to find the solution

Comment: Thank you @Jolta, it was that! On the MIB File I added a new variable to all notifications to pass the severity level, and mapped that on TEMIP.

Answer (score 1):

Severity is not an attribute of an SNMP trap, in general.

Which SNMP manager are you using? Most likely, the manager is mapping some MIB variable from the trap into the Severity field of its internal alarm format, but you're not providing that variable in your snmptrap command.

You probably need to study the documentation of your SNMP manager to find the solution.